How can I redirect the output of recessed ceiling lights?
I have a vaulted ceiling in the living room with two recessed lights that shine right in your face when seated.  How can I redirect the light?

How about a few pictures of the light fixtures you're concerned with.

What you need is a light that is gimbaled. ( The light itself can be tilted in multiple directions to aim the beam.)
Depending on the type of fixture in the ceiling there are various retrofit or replacement possibilities.
Most of the big box stores have options. If you cannot find anything, consult your local lighting store.

The gimbaled fixture is sometimes called an "eyeball" — in particular, that is the name of the orange store category.
